# How can I use fetch instead of request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I am making react-native app which shows information about our school. I wrote information in google spreadsheet and made my application crawl it by request and require.

```
var date = new Date()
var year = date.getFullYear()
var month = new String(date.getMonth() + 1)
var day = new String(date.getDate())

if (month.length == 1) {
  month = "0" + month
}

if (day.length == 1) {
  day = "0" + day
}

const today = (year + month + day)

// arrays to save each information
var breakfast = [];
var lunch = [];
var dinner = [];
var quote = [];


var request = require('request');
//get information from google spreadsheet
request('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzwGjC5GU3RK448VeJtGm6xXpf_UzFgps3zi5bv9gfQcfsOervJ6RYinWFi-UzGbNMg/exec?sheetName=%EC%8B%9C%ED%8A%B81', function (err, res, body) {
// get information in body tag by json form
  var dataArray = JSON.parse(body)
  for (let i = 0; i < dataArray.data.length; i++) {
// find today's information
    if (String(dataArray.data[i].gdate) == today) {
      breakfast = dataArray.data[i].gbreakfast.split(',')    
      console.log(breakfast)  
      lunch = dataArray.data[i].glunch.split(',')
      dinner = dataArray.data[i].gdinner.split(',')
      quote = "\"" + dataArray.data[i].gquote + "\""
      break
    }
  }
});
```

It worked without error when ran in expo web(snack). But when I tried to build the application,

```
Unable to resolve module crypto from C:\Users\munge\SEMA\node_modules\request\lib\helpers.js: crypto could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules\request\node_modules
  node_modules
  ..\node_modules

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
  2 |
  3 | var jsonSafeStringify = require('json-stringify-safe')
> 4 | var crypto = require('crypto')
    |                       ^
  5 | var Buffer = require('safe-buffer').Buffer
  6 |
  7 | var defer = typeof setImmediate === 'undefined'
```

error above occurred. I guess it happened because of request, so I want to change my code using fetch instead of request. How can I do?

Comment: Good idea, because the maintainer of request [deprecated it a long time ago](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142). If you want to use `fetch` then [check out the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). It's pretty darn easy once you take just a cursory glance at them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch api is pretty easy to use, some look into the documentation will let you ready to go.

As for your actual code I did some updates so you can test the fetch api, here it is:

```js
const list = async () => {
    var date = new Date()
    var year = date.getFullYear()
    var month = new String(date.getMonth() + 1)
    var day = new String(date.getDate())

    if (month.length === 1) {
      month = "0" + month
    }

    if (day.length === 1) {
      day = "0" + day
    }

    const today = (year + month + day)

    // arrays to save each information
    let breakfast = [];
    let lunch = [];
    let dinner = [];
    let quote = [];

    try{
      //get information from google spreadsheet
      const response  = await fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzwGjC5GU3RK448VeJtGm6xXpf_UzFgps3zi5bv9gfQcfsOervJ6RYinWFi-UzGbNMg/exec?sheetName=%EC%8B%9C%ED%8A%B81')
      if (response.ok) {
        var dataArray = await response.json()
        for (let i = 0; i < dataArray.data.length; i++) {
          // find today's information
          console.log(dataArray.data[i].gdate)
          if (String(dataArray.data[i].gdate) === today) {
            breakfast = dataArray.data[i].gbreakfast.split(',')
            console.log(breakfast)
            lunch = dataArray.data[i].glunch.split(',')
            dinner = dataArray.data[i].gdinner.split(',')
            quote = "\"" + dataArray.data[i].gquote + "\""
            break
          }
        }
      } else {
        console.log('failed to fetch info')
      }
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('failed to fetch info')
    }
  }
  
  list()
```

Just a heads up, I'm using fetch with async/await here, you may see some implementations using Promises, it's basically the same outcome.

Success on your project